# Ordinal multivariate analysis

Tags: multivariate-analysis, ordinal-data, likert

I know that there has been many questions regarding analysing likert scales  but I still have not found the easiest way to approach my analyse.

I have done a survey with 100 participants that has 3 groups of questions based on the likert scale (1-7), with 8 questions in each group. Depending on the answers of the first group of questions, I would like to see the how it correlate with the second and the third group of questions.

My hypothesis is that if the participants answer positively to group 1 questions, that it will correlate more to positive answers in groups 2 then group 3 questions. I therefor wanted to compare two groups of likert scales with each other to see how the correlate (group 1 and 2 + groups 1 and 3).

I have started to look into conducting a principle component analysis as a data reduction technique to reduce the amount to components, but Im not sure if this is the best way to approach it.

I know there is probably several complicated ways to do this that may be more correct then others, but I'm looking for an easy way that I can easily understand. Any help would be very much appreciated!